# Couldn't load the data for this visual..Error in PBI Service with Databricks directQuery connection

Tags: powerbi, azure-databricks, powerbi-datasource

I have created a working report on Power BI with Databricks as DirectQuery. Published in it service.
But No visuals are loading. error is : Couldn't load the data for this visual.

Dataset based on databricks directQuery is getting refreshed in PBI service when I click on refresh. but still this error.
going through multiple articles for the same is not helping.
If anyone can please put your thoughts/suggestions/help?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

> error : Couldn't load the data for this visual.

`DirectQuery` will be slower when dealing with large volumes of data. Thus, this error is possible due to the high data volume. To resolve this,

- **Try reducing the data volume** by filtering the data or aggregating it before loading it into Power BI.
- Make sure that the **data model is correctly defined** and that the relationships between the tables and queries are set up correctly.

**Reference**: [Direct Query -1 million row limitation in Power BI ... - Microsoft Fabric Community](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Direct-Query-1-million-row-limitation-in-Power-BI-Premium/m-p/847202)